# ActionScript 3 Override Methods + Increase Visibility

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, methods, overriding

When I extend a class I want to override methods and change their accessibility like a protected method should be public in a certain class. When I compile it says: "Incompatible override". I can't reduce nor can I increase the visibility.

Reducing wouldn't make sense and I don't need it but I was able to **increase method visibility** in Java. Why not in ActionScript 3 ?

```
public class OldClass
{
    protected function doStuff() : void
    {}
}
public class NewClass extends OldClass
{
    override public function doStuff() : void
    {}
}
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're not doing anything wrong. That's just how the language works. From the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fcd.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f3c) (emphasis added):

> Static methods are not inherited and cannot be overridden. Instance methods, however, are inherited by subclasses and can be overridden as long as the following two criteria are met:
>
> - ...
> - **The override method must have the same level of access control** as the base class method. Methods marked as internal have the same level of access control as methods that have no access control specifier.
> - The override method must have the same number of parameters as the base class method.
> - The override method parameters must have the same data type annotations as the parameters in the base class method.
> - The override method must have the same return type as the base class method.

Comment: ActionScript 3 is a messed up language. I just noticed that I can't change width and height of a Sprite not before I drew something to the sprites graphics. This is ridiculous. But thanks for the info!

Comment: OT, but that is expected behavior @mini-me . An empty `Sprite` should always have a width of zero. Getting the width of a `Sprite` returns the width of all its children (after transformations has been applied). Setting the width of a `Sprite` simply changes the scaling that's applied.

Comment: You know, I had my own sprites in Java before starting with Actionscript-3 and I still like mine better because I could just add a new invisible child sprite with nonzero dimensions and use it for collision detection. Worked pretty well altogether. And AS-3 took the "Sprite" name away from me -.-

Comment: @Bitterblue AS3 did not take the "Sprite" name away from you, all you have to do is define your own custom namespace.

https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/namespaces.html

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere I know. And I did that in the end. But compiler and organizing imports always bugged me with those 2 classes. MSVS deals with class and namespace names far better.